# rubyzip with dynamic csv files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, rubyzip

I had an application with rails 4 & rubyzip gem installed.
I have 3 tables - students, exams & results.

I followed this video http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel

I'm able to download individual table csv files but not all 3 at a single click.

And I want to download all these 3 table csv files as a zip file with rubyzip or something else.

Please help me. I searched every end of google but didn't find an accurate result.

Comment: I was able to achieve this using this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4350689/1387338