# Rails public/system for user files

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dragonfly-gem

Both Rails gems **DragonFly** and **Paperclip** use public/system folder to store uploaded files.

As far as I know this folder is accessible by everybody - at least the root files, 404.html or others.

How can I protect these uploaded files? Is there any configuration options available?

I need to process transcoded video files which are generated from user uploads and make them available with some permission checks.

Are there any recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about dragonfile but you can change the paperclip file upload options.

Could you use Amazon S3 instead?

Add the following to your envrionment:

```
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
}
```

Make sure you've got the s3 gem installed by adding this to your gemfile:

```
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

Does that help or do you need to keep them on your server to process??

-- edit --

Apparently heroku recommend using a temp file if you can't use s3. Have a read of this post:

[How can I change the upload directory for paperclip on heroku to /tmp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136773/how-can-i-change-the-upload-directory-for-paperclip-on-heroku-to-tmp)

Comment: I need put files on local storage - security requirements. Thats the problem here

Comment: Not too much. Sorry but I need some guide about applying permissions to uploaded files

Comment: Ok. You might want to consider altering your question a little as it's a bit misleading. Just add that last comment in and someone will pick it up I'm sure.